# PyQt5 pop up qmessage instead of flashing back when an error occurs

Tags: python, excel, pandas, exception, pyqt5

This is my code.

```
try:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(r'report.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        to_excel(self.output, writer)
except Exception as e:
    #print(e)
    QMessageBox.warning(self,'error',e,QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No,QMessageBox.Yes)
```

I want to confirm that there will be problems when writing to excel, such as the file has been opened.Then use the qmessage pop-up window to prompt for this information, but it will cause flash back.
I want to know how to change my code and how to use the try statement correctly.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it will cause flash back"?

Comment: @musicamante
Flash back like this：Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409).

Comment: I don't know why you call it like this (I've never seen that terminology for a crash). In any case you should provide a [mre]. You're not editing a pyuic generated file, right?

Comment: You can't pass an exception object to `QMessageBox.warning`. Use `str(e)` instead.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you. I really didn't think it was a type problem. I thought it was a thread conflict.